# Register consumption of per-thread Program Counters in Volta

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I was curious to know the meaning behind the footnote at the bottom of Table 2 in page 18 in [Volta whitepaper](http://composter.com.ua/documents/Volta-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf). While the table indicates that Volta has 256 KB registers per SM similar to its predecessors, the footprint mentions that

> The per-thread program counter (PC) that forms part of the improved SIMT model typically requires two of the
>   register slots per thread.

Does it mean that for every running thread in Volta you have 2 reserved 32-bit registers that keep track of the PC? If yes, does it also mean that this reservation is static in a sense that regardless of how many threads are residing on your SM, 2048(maximum number of threads allowed on SM)*2=4096 registers are taken? Also, can this reservation be eliminated by compiling for a CC lower than 7.0?

Comment: Do you actually need a Volta GPU to check this? Couldn't you just compile and disassemble some code using the CUDA 9  toolkit for the Volta architecture?

Comment: You're certainly right @talonmies. Going to install CUDA 9 and see the compiled assembly.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for every running thread, 2 additional registers are allocated from SM's register file when compiling for Compute Capability 7.0.

Using CUDA 9.1, I compiled the following simple saxpy kernel

```
__global__ void saxpy(float* out, float a, float* x, float* y) {
  out[ threadIdx.x ] = a * x[ threadIdx.x ] + y[ threadIdx.x ];
}
```

for CC 6.1 and 7.0 with maximum compiler optimization flag (`-03`) applied. While using `cuobjdump -res-usage` on the binary for CC 6.1 shows that 8 registers are used for every thread in the kernel, the same command on the binary for CC 7.0 reports that register usage per thread is 10. I also printed the sass using  `cuobjdump -sass`. Below is the content for the binary for CC 6.1. You can see architected registers with indices 0 to 7 are all used.

```
    code for sm_61
            Function : _Z5saxpyPffS_S_
   .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                              /* 0x083fc400e3e007f6 */
    /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];                          /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
    /*0010*/                   S2R R0, SR_TID.X;                              /* 0xf0c8000002170000 */
    /*0018*/                   SHL R6, R0.reuse, 0x2;                         /* 0x3848000000270006 */
                                                                              /* 0x081fc840fec007f5 */
    /*0028*/                   SHR.U32 R0, R0, 0x1e;                          /* 0x3828000001e70000 */
    /*0030*/                   IADD R2.CC, R6.reuse, c[0x0][0x150];           /* 0x4c10800005470602 */
    /*0038*/                   IADD.X R3, R0.reuse, c[0x0][0x154];            /* 0x4c10080005570003 */
                                                                              /* 0x001f8800eec007f0 */
    /*0048*/         {         IADD R4.CC, R6, c[0x0][0x158];                 /* 0x4c10800005670604 */
    /*0050*/                   LDG.E R2, [R2];        }                       /* 0xeed4200000070202 */
    /*0058*/                   IADD.X R5, R0, c[0x0][0x15c];                  /* 0x4c10080005770005 */
                                                                              /* 0x001fdc00fec00771 */
    /*0068*/                   LDG.E R4, [R4];                                /* 0xeed4200000070404 */
    /*0070*/                   IADD R6.CC, R6, c[0x0][0x140];                 /* 0x4c10800005070606 */
    /*0078*/                   IADD.X R7, R0, c[0x0][0x144];                  /* 0x4c10080005170007 */
                                                                              /* 0x001ffc001e2047f2 */
    /*0088*/                   FFMA R0, R2, c[0x0][0x148], R4;                /* 0x4980020005270200 */
    /*0090*/                   STG.E [R6], R0;                                /* 0xeedc200000070600 */
    /*0098*/                   EXIT;                                          /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                                              /* 0x001f8000fc0007ff */
    /*00a8*/                   BRA 0xa0;                                      /* 0xe2400fffff07000f */
    /*00b0*/                   NOP;                                           /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
    /*00b8*/                   NOP;                                           /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
    ..........................
```

Now for CC 7.0.

```
    code for sm_70
           Function : _Z5saxpyPffS_S_
   .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM70 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM70)"
    /*0000*/              @!PT SHFL.IDX PT, RZ, RZ, RZ, RZ;                          /* 0x000000fffffff389 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fe200000e00ff */
    /*0010*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x28];                                 /* 0x00000a0000017a02 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fd00000000f00 */
    /*0020*/                   S2R R6, SR_TID.X;                                     /* 0x0000000000067919 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000e220000002100 */
    /*0030*/                   MOV R7, 0x4;                                          /* 0x0000000400077802 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fca0000000f00 */
    /*0040*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R2, R6.reuse, R7.reuse, c[0x0][0x170];  /* 0x00005c0006027625 */
                                                                                     /* 0x0c1fe400078e0007 */
    /*0050*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R4, R6, R7, c[0x0][0x178];              /* 0x00005e0006047625 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fd000078e0007 */
    /*0060*/                   LDG.E.SYS R2, [R2];                                   /* 0x0000000002027381 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000e2800001ee900 */
    /*0070*/                   LDG.E.SYS R4, [R4];                                   /* 0x0000000004047381 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000e2200001ee900 */
    /*0080*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R6, R6, R7, c[0x0][0x160];              /* 0x0000580006067625 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fe400078e0007 */
    /*0090*/                   FFMA R0, R2, c[0x0][0x168], R4;                       /* 0x00005a0002007a23 */
                                                                                     /* 0x001fd00000000004 */
    /*00a0*/                   STG.E.SYS [R6], R0;                                   /* 0x0000000006007386 */
                                                                                     /* 0x0001e2000010e900 */
    /*00b0*/                   EXIT;                                                 /* 0x000000000000794d */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fea0003800000 */
    /*00c0*/                   BRA 0xc0;                                             /* 0xfffffff000007947 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fc0000383ffff */
    /*00d0*/                   NOP;                                                  /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
    /*00e0*/                   NOP;                                                  /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
    /*00f0*/                   NOP;                                                  /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                                     /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
```

You see that again only architected register 0 to 7 (except for `R3` and `R5`) are used inside the code block. There is also the use of `RZ` at the beginning of the kernel. Now I do not see where three other registers are, which makes me inclined to believe that two registers are reserved for tracking thread's PC.

Anyway, I came to the conclusion I stated at the beginning of the post with clearly insufficient observations. Any contribution to improve this answer is appreciated.